# Getting error while runing npm run test in CI

Tags: javascript, cypress, package.json

here is my package.json:

```
{
  
  "name": "cypressautomation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "/node_modules/.bin/cypress  run "
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "^7.0.1",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "mochawesome-report-generator": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

I have built some test scripts, and after I saved all files and run `npm run test` I get the error:

> cypressautomation@1.0.0 test > /node_modules/.bin/cypress run
> The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: You don't have a script named `test` under the `scripts` section of you `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might  be facing issues with relative/absolute path conventions.

First let us cover the basis. From the command line at the folder where the `package.json` file is located, run `npm install` for the packages to be downloaded into the local `node_modules` folder.

You could change the command on package.json to:

```
"test": "cypress run"
```

this way we leave npm to figure out where cypress is located (will be in the node_modules folder and npm 'knows' about it)

then try the test command again:

```
npm run test
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to run project in correct path.  if your npm run test is not working, first in command prompt try running command then add the same in package json.
I use this coomand to run project  ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).